# Using sed with regex to subtitute string

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have this xml data

```
<institution>
    <id>83812745840</id>
    <code>2701811200</code>
    <full_name>full name 1</full_name>
    <address>adress 1</address>
    <institution_type>
        <id>191</id>
        <code>inst code 1</code>
        <name>institution name1</name>
    </institution_type>
    <place>
        <id>812007638</id>
        <name>place-name_1</name>
        <code>415995</code></place>
    <activity>
        <code>811855905</code>
        <name>act-name-1</name>
        <equipment_specialty>false</equipment_specialty>
    </activity>
</institution>
```

I need to change `<code>` with `<code_>` and `<place><name>` with `<place><name_>`. How can be this done with sed and regex?

I tried with `sed 's/<institution>.*<code>.*<\/code>/<institution>.*<code_>.*<\/code_>/g'` but the .* on replaced string become .* not any string that matched with the regex.

Comment: WHat did you tried? Let us see what you did on your own.

Comment: There's a dozen ways to do this. What issue/part of this are you struggling with? Someone could write an exact solution to this for you, but it won't be long-term helpful to anyone

Comment: I tried with sed 's/<institution>.*<code>.*<\/code>/<institution>.*<code_>.*<\/code_>/g' but the .* on replaced string become .* not any string that matched with the regex.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand with how this sed and regex works.

Comment: 1. `sed` processes each line of data from a file separately. It takes a lot of doing to "glue" together multiple lines of a file so you can find the `<name>` that is under the `<place>` section. 2. When a direct match can be make (char for char), then a reg-ex is of no extra value. You can get your first replacment done with `sed 's/code[>]/code_>/g' file` To understand your second problem, you'll need to read thru the [Grymoires sed tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . It's really worth starting at the beginning. Tell your boss you need some time to become a sed master ;-) .GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is not use XML/HTML parsers while you always should use them when dealing with XML/HTML data:

the right way with `xmlstarlet` tool:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -r '//institution/code' -v 'code_' -r '//place/name' -v 'name_' input.xml
```

The output:

```
<institution>
  <id>83812745840</id>
  <code_>2701811200</code_>
  <full_name>full name 1</full_name>
  <address>adress 1</address>
  <institution_type>
    <id>191</id>
    <code>inst code 1</code>
    <name>institution name1</name>
  </institution_type>
  <place>
    <id>812007638</id>
    <name_>place-name_1</name_>
    <code>415995</code>
  </place>
  <activity>
    <code>811855905</code>
    <name>act-name-1</name>
    <equipment_specialty>false</equipment_specialty>
  </activity>
</institution>
```

---

To modify the file inplace add `-L` option: `xmlstarlet ed -O -L ....`

Comment: Well actually I have done this with xmlstarlet. But the xmlstartlet command need to be installed first and my employer don't have root access on server he is working with.

Comment: that's a weak reason to dive and propagate weak, fragile and instable approaches like manipulating xml/html with sed. That will never be called a good approach in sane